# Converting an array of ints to corresponding chars

Tags: python, arrays

Im trying to convert an array of ints that I want to convert into their corresponding chars in the alphabet, e.g `1 = a`. This is what the first row of my matrix looks like:

```
[[16 12  9  9 12  9  9  9  8 12  9  9 12 19  3]]
```

I tried Using the method below but this produces an error, is there a way to do this with arrays?

```
print chr(labels1[0] + ord('a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
>>> l = [[16, 12,  9,  9, 12,  9,  9,  9,  8, 12,  9,  9, 12, 19,  3]]
>>> [chr(c + ord('a') - 1) for c in l[0]]
['p', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'h', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'l', 's', 'c']
```

Or, if you'd like them as a single string:

```
>>> ''.join(chr(c + ord('a') - 1) for c in l[0])
'pliiliiihliilsc'
```

Comment: is it possible to use this method on arrays with more than 1 rows?

Comment: @cockmagic: Yes - you need another loop or another level of list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one word in there (as one list), then this should work just fine

```
In [74]: L = [16, 12,  9,  9, 12,  9,  9,  9,  8, 12,  9,  9, 12, 19,  3]

In [75]: [chr(i+ord('a')-1) for i in L]
Out[75]: ['p', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'h', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'l', 's', 'c']

In [76]: ''.join([chr(i+ord('a')-1) for i in L])
Out[76]: 'pliiliiihliilsc'
```

If you have multiples words that may need to be combined with spaces between them, then this should do the trick:

```
In [77]: LL = [[16, 12,  9,  9, 12,  9,  9,  9,  8, 12,  9,  9, 12, 19,  3]]

In [78]: ' '.join([''.join([chr(i+ord('a')-1) for i in L]) for L in LL])
Out[78]: 'pliiliiihliilsc'
```

Comment: may want to use `unichr` if there is __any__ possibility of a value greater than 255

Answer (score 0):

if you want `a=1` so you want the letters based on those orders in alphabet so can use `string` module :

```
>>> import string 
>>> l=[16,12,  9,  9, 12,  9,  9,  9,  8, 12,  9,  9, 12, 19, 3]
>>> ''.join([string.letters[i-1] for i in l])
'pliiliiihliilsc'
```

`string.letters` is a connected string of the alphabets !

```
>>> string.letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```